# Rewriting Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, matrix-analysis

im considering a pole placement problem in control theory and my controler has a specific form:
$$R=I_n\otimes q$$
where $I_n$ is the identitiy matrix of size $n$ and $q\in\Re^k$ is a vector of the free paramters, $q=[q_1,q_2,...,q_k]^T,q_i\in\Re$ and $\otimes$ is the kronecker-product.
E.g. for $n=3$ and $k=2$ this becomes

$$R_{3,2}= I_3\otimes q =\begin{bmatrix}
q_1 & 0 & 0 \\
q_2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & q_1 & 0 \\
0 & q_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & q_1 \\
0 & 0 & q_2 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

My goal would be to rewrite $R$ in some form, s.t. the vector $q$ is isolated from the kronecker product or that the kronecker product $\otimes$ dissapears completely - something like $R=...\cdot q\cdot ...$ or $R=...\cdot diag(q) \cdot ...$. However i found no sources in the Internet, on how i could rearrange the matrix $R$ in a proper way that isolates $q$.

If you have any idea, please let me know:)

Best regards
BigL

Comment: Since the map $q \mapsto I_n \otimes q$ is linear, you can write it in an operator-sum form. That is, there exist finite sets of matrices $\{A_j\}$ and $\{B_j\}$ such that $R = \sum_j A_j q B_j$. Would that be good enough? You probably need $n$ terms in the sum, but I haven't done the calculation yet.

Can I ask for some context, or an explanation of why you would want to do this though?

Comment: Hi Nathaniel, thanks for the response :)
The background of my question is control theory, where i have an controller-matrix $C\in\Re^{p\times n}$ in vectorized form: $$c = vec(C)=U\cdot q$$ with a given, fixed $ U\in\Re^{np\times k}$ and the free design parameter in $q\in\Re^{k}$. I was reversing the vec-operator by
$$C=(vec(I_n)^T\otimes I_p)(I_n\otimes Uq)=\underbrace{(vec(I_n)^T\otimes I_p)(I_n\otimes U)}_{\Psi } \underbrace{(I_n\otimes q)}_{R}$$
where $\Psi$ contains just numbers and $R$ contains my free design parameters $q$, which i want to use to design a controller for the plant.

Comment: However since the elements of $q$ are somehow "trapped" in the kronecker product, i can't use the known methods of control theory for pole placement so far, so i wondered how you could rewrite $R$ in any form.

Could you explain your idea of writing it in an operator-sum form further? How do i find the matrices $A_j$ and $B_j$?

Best regards
BigL :)

Comment: You can choose $A_j = e_j \otimes I_k$ and $B_j = e_j^T$ for $j = 1,2,\ldots,n$, where $e_j$ is the $j$-th standard basis column vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, however the sum is still a problem for me.
I had another idea, by diagonalizing the matrix, i.e. by rearranging as follows:
$$R_{3,2}= \begin{bmatrix}q_1&0&0\\q_2&0&0\\0&q_2&0\\0&q_2&0\\0&0&q_3\\0&0&q_3\end{bmatrix}  = diag([q_1,q_2,q_1,q_2,q_1,q_2]) \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}=P_1 diag([q_1,q_1,q_1,q_2,q_2,q_2]) P_2 \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} $$
with two Permutationmatrices $P_{1,2}$.


Do you know if there's a way to rewrite the diagnoal matrix and extracting the vector $q$ somehow?

Comment: If the sum or Kronecker product is a problem, then I doubt there is a way that will do what you want. This feels morally equivalent to turning a general linear system into a rank-1 linear system, which isn't possible in general.

Comment: alright, thank you :)